# WooCommerce, hiding shipping method's' when free shipping is available

Tags: hide, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and found out that I'm able to hide shipping method when free shipping is available.

but the problem now is I need to hide two instead of one. when ever I try hiding two methods my whole page go black.

I need expert to help me solve it. thanks a million in advance!!

```
// Hide standard shipping option when free shipping is available
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 'hide_standard_shipping_when_free_is_available' , 10, 1 );

/**
 *  Hide Standard Shipping option when free shipping is available
 * 
 * @param array $available_methods
 */
function hide_standard_shipping_when_free_is_available( $available_methods ) {

    if( isset( $available_methods['free_shipping'] ) AND isset( $available_methods['local_delivery'], ['flat_rate'] ) ) {

        // remove standard shipping option
        unset( $available_methods['local_delivery'], ['flat_rate'] );
    }

    return $available_methods;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an plugin for advanced free shipping options. This includes an option to hide other shipping when free is available.

You might like it: http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-advanced-free-shipping/

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce Advanced Free Shipping plugin is good but
It doesn't work hiding other shipping methods when free shipping.
The plugin can be enabled on woocommerce admin settings but checking the option to hide other shipping methods cannot be checked and save. I tried overiding it on WP option db but seems it doesn't working also. There seems to be problem with the plugin code.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'xa_hide_shipping_rates_when_free_is_available', 10, 2);

function xa_hide_shipping_rates_when_free_is_available($rates, $package)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $version = "2.6";
    if (version_compare($woocommerce->version, $version, ">=")) {
        foreach( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $free_shipping = $rates[$key];
                // Unset all rates.
                $rates = array();
                // Restore free shipping rate.
                $rates[$key] = $free_shipping;
                return $rates;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (isset($rates['free_shipping'])) {
          // Below code is for unsetting single shipping method/option.
            // unset($rates['flat_rate']);
            $free_shipping = $rates['free_shipping'];
            // Unset all rates.
            $rates = array();
            // Restore free shipping rate.
        $rates['free_shipping'] = $free_shipping;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
```

Refer this [link](https://www.xadapter.com/woocommerce-2-6-hide-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/) for details